# Simple Stored procedure in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am not strong in `PhpMyAdmin`, nor in `MySql` nonstandard syntax. I am trying to create a simple stored procedure using `PhpMyAdmin` and the engine just repeats the same:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3

Simple stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_test()
BEGIN
  DECLARE int_val INT;

  SET int_val = int_val + 1;
  SELECT int_val;
END;
```

Here is the version:

```
select @@version

5.6.28
```

I am starting to hate `MySql`. Why I can not manage to create such a simple stored procedure?

Comment: you forget the delimiter. and also when you call this procedure it will show null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some `delimiter` to the code. This should do:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE proc_test()
BEGIN
  DECLARE int_val INT;

  SET int_val = int_val + 1;
  SELECT int_val;

END $$
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use the `DELIMITER`. [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_test()
BEGIN
  DECLARE int_val INT;    
  SET int_val = int_val + 1;
  SELECT int_val;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

but when you call this procedure it always show  `null`. so you should set `int_val` value by `DEFAULT` value or using `SET`

```
DECLARE int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
```

OR

```
SET int_val = 0
```